# R:Converting char to time (duration(hms))

Tags: r, dataframe, time, types, char

I'm attempting to change a column type from `char` to `time` and am not getting the results expected.  Description and `dput` output follow:

I'm attempting to change the column called Duration from char to time:

```
structure(list(RouteID = c(12817402, 12817404, 12817406, 12817425,
12817426, 12817446, 12817447, 12817455, 12817481, 12817499, 12817599,
12817603, 12817631, 12817636, 12817655), PaymentPlan = c("Subscriber",
"Casual", "Subscriber", "Casual", "Casual", "Casual", "Subscriber",
"Subscriber", "Casual", "Casual", "Subscriber", "Casual", "Casual",
"Casual", "Casual"), StartHub = c("NW Johnson at Jamison Square",
"SE Ladd at Hawthorne", NA, "SE 50th at Clinton", NA, "SE 30th at Division",
"SW Morrison at 18th", "NE 42nd at Hancock", NA, NA, "SW River at Montgomery",
NA, "NW Flanders at 14th", NA, NA), StartLatitude = c(45.5286366,
45.5120818, 45.522783, 45.503506, 45.5086555, 45.50468892, 45.52196048,
45.536898, 45.5041753, 45.5014807, 45.50910258, 45.5233209, 45.52579919,
45.5315017, 45.5218677), StartLongitude = c(-122.6820195, -122.6533493,
-122.6811195, -122.611066, -122.6547299, -122.6345551, -122.6896772,
-122.619969, -122.6612413, -122.6557978, -122.6735169, -122.6963404,
-122.6855063, -122.6834541, -122.6747676), StartDate = c("12/1/2019",
"12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019",
"12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019",
"12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019"), StartTime = structure(c(1020,
1140, 1200, 2700, 2880, 6660, 6960, 8280, 13020, 15900, 23040,
23340, 24780, 24840, 25500), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"),
EndHub = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "NW Couch at 11th",
"SE 2nd Pl at Tilikum Way", "NW Raleigh at 21st", NA, "SW 5th at Morrison"
), EndLatitude = c(45.524531, 45.5086555, 45.5090834, 45.5422432,
45.5041753, 45.5034396, 45.5312952, 45.5317187, 45.5014807,
45.5041753, 45.52374151, 45.50624163, 45.53409115, 45.5144089,
45.51889487), EndLongitude = c(-122.6744613, -122.6547299,
-122.6840225, -122.604573, -122.6612413, -122.639666, -122.6946193,
-122.6306539, -122.6557978, -122.6612413, -122.6818129, -122.6633379,
-122.6949424, -122.6840143, -122.6774061), EndDate = c("12/1/2019",
"12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019",
"12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019",
"12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/1/2019"), EndTime = structure(c(1740,
1440, 1860, 4200, 3780, 6840, 8220, 10560, 13380, 16500,
23880, 24420, 25140, 26100, 25800), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), TripType = c(NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_), BikeID = c(6516, 24819, 7342, 6636, 24819,
7109, 6396, 6082, 24819, 24819, 6464, 7252, 6310, 6040, 6249
), BikeName = c("0060 BIKETOWN", "0199 BIKETOWN", "1016 LATINX HERITAGE MONTH",
"0825 BIKETOWN", "0199 BIKETOWN", "0749 BIKETOWN", "0707 BIKETOWN",
"0084 BIKETOWN", "0199 BIKETOWN", "0199 BIKETOWN", "0559 BIKETOWN",
"0845 BIKETOWN", "0868 BIKETOWN", "0901 BIKETOWN", "0300 BIKETOWN"
), Distance_Miles = c(0.72, 0.44, 1.18, 2.99, 1.36, 0.31,
0.89, 0.71, 0.58, 0.83, 1.5, 2.46, 1.02, 1.66, 0.34), Duration = c("0:11:10",
"0:05:18", "0:11:31", "0:24:28", "0:15:11", "0:03:11", "0:21:02",
"0:37:45", "0:05:38", "0:10:26", "0:13:33", "0:17:27", "0:06:42",
"0:20:58", "0:04:51"), RentalAccessPath = c("keypad", "mobile",
"mobile", "keypad", "mobile", "mobile", "keypad", "mobile",
"mobile", "mobile", "keypad", "keypad", "keypad", "keypad",
"keypad_rfid_card"), MultipleRental = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I ran this:

```
library(lubridate)
X2020_07 <- as.duration(hms(X2020_07$Duration))
```

where `X df` is structured similar to the `dput df` above.
The type was changed from `char` to `time` but there is only 1 column!:

```
new("Duration", .Data = c(1687, 73, 1499, 691, 475, 350, 538,
3018, 1594, 2447, 1160, 1185, 469, 1090, 424))
```

The goal is to preserve the 19 column `df` when it's piped to another `df` of the same name , i.e. `X2020_07 <- X2020` while changing the column type to time.

Given my limited knowledge of `R` (I am enjoying learning) unsure what else I should be looking into. Appreciate guidance and solutions!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `as.duration` results in the correct column type.
Here is a solution using the pipe operator of `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

X2020_07 <- X2020 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Duration = lubridate::as.duration(lubridate::hms(Duration)))
```